# Car plate number text recognition problem

Tags: image-processing, text, python-tesseract, text-recognition, text-segmentation

we all know that any OCR nowadays is already established. But I can't get it right. I'm trying to recognized the text from car's number plate images. I've done image processing. Here is my code.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os
import csv

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

def ocr_with_threshold(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold)
    return text.strip()

# Folder path containing the image files
folder_path = "nombor_plat_s_resize"

# Create a CSV file to store the results
csv_file = open('results.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Image', 'Min Threshold', 'Max Threshold', 'Extracted Text'])

# Iterate over all image files in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

        min_threshold_successful = 1.0
        max_threshold_successful = 1.0
        successful_text = None

        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        mser = cv2.MSER_create()
        regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(gray)

        for region in regions:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(region)
            roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            result = ocr_with_threshold(roi)

            if result:
                if min_threshold_successful == 1.0 and max_threshold_successful == 1.0:
                    min_threshold_successful = max_threshold_successful = result
                    successful_text = result
                else:
                    if result < min_threshold_successful:
                        min_threshold_successful = result
                    if result > max_threshold_successful:
                        max_threshold_successful = result
                    if successful_text != result:
                        successful_text = None

        # Write the results to the CSV file
        csv_writer.writerow([filename, min_threshold_successful, max_threshold_successful, successful_text])

# Close the CSV file
csv_file.close()
```

This is some of the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpSzU.png)

anyone can help me to understand the images?

I tried to do the text recognition using the pytesseract with the help of thresholding and MSER technique. I expect at least it get 60% correct but 100% not correct. This is the actual plate number or text that can be seen by eyes. [actual plate number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5zDm.png)
This is the images used for the test. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qHKQDhXy0W--AyV2YAFErSLV67xsNT9m?usp=drive_link